# MySQL. When trying to delete few duplicate rows, it deletes the last and does not delete any further

Tags: java, mysql

I've got tables `Artist`, `Concert`, and `Artist_Concert`, which contains many-to many connections between `Artist` and `Concert`.

The problem is: after adding a `Concert` with few `Artists`, when trying to delete rows from `Artist_Concert`, it only deletes only one row and nothing happens when trying to delete any others.

This is how I'm trying to delete rows in Java:

```
stat = connect.createStatement();
        res = stat.executeQuery ("SELECT idConcert FROM concerthall.concert where ConcertName = '"+conc+"';");
        res.first();
        int idconc = res.getInt(1);
        stat.execute ("DELETE FROM concerthall.artist_concert WHERE idConc="+idconc+"");
```

Artist

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `concerthall`.`Artist` (
`idArtist` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`ArtName` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`ArtFee` INT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`idArtist`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

Artist-Concert

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `concerthall`.`Artist_Concert` (
`idCA` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`idArt` INT NOT NULL,
`IdConc` INT NOT NULL,
INDEX `idart_idx` (`idArt` ASC),
INDEX `idconc_idx` (`IdConc` ASC),
PRIMARY KEY (`idCA`),
CONSTRAINT `idart2`
FOREIGN KEY (`idArt`)
REFERENCES `concerthall`.`Artist` (`idArtist`)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
CONSTRAINT `idconct4`
FOREIGN KEY (`IdConc`)
REFERENCES `concerthall`.`Concert` (`idConcert`)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

Concert

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `concerthall`.`Concert` (
`idConcert` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`ConcertName` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`ConcertDateTime` DATETIME NOT NULL,
`Organizator` INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`idConcert`),
INDEX `concertorg_idx` (`Organizator` ASC),
CONSTRAINT `concertorg`
FOREIGN KEY (`Organizator`)
REFERENCES `concerthall`.`Organizator` (`idOrganizator`)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to drop duplicates is:

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE table ADD UNIQUE INDEX( a, b );
```

In the INDEX() part, enter the name(s) of the column(s) you only want unique entries for. I think you want:

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE concerthall.artist_concert ADD UNIQUE INDEX( idConc );
```

Then drop the index.